# Capture active windows and save with title as filename

Tags: windows, screenshot

I would like to save screenshots of an app, and looking for a tool which automatically saves screenshots.

Picasa 3 saves the screenshots when running, and it gives the filename according to the title of captured window, but it saves to bmp, which are huge, and if I make several schreenshots, it drops, if working on the saving. So if I am speedy, half of my pictures are dropped.

So do you know a schreenshot saving tool which gives the filename according to the captured windows's title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ZScreen](https://code.google.com/p/zscreen/) does that.

In the "File Naming Configurator" (Menu "Configure" -> "File Naming...") you can use various variables to construct the resulting file names. Among them "Title of Active Window".

It takes a couple of minutes to configure all the various options but once that's done it gets out of your way and lets you do your job.

Comment: Thanks! Looks nice. After I can't get answer I wrote my own in C#, and did my task with that. But it looks good.